# robotframework: Dictionary has no key error

Tags: list, dictionary, append, robotframework

When I run the test DICT-WITH-LISTS, I get an error that says dictionary has no key. But as you can see I did print the key and the key whose value is meant to be a list seems to be there.
Not sure what I am doing wrong and why my key is showing up differently in the error message.
I would greatly appreciate any help in resolving this issue

```
*** Variables ***
${p1}=  P-1
${f1}=  F-2
${p2}=  P-2
${p3}=  P-3


*** Test Cases ***
DICT-WITH-LISTS
    [tags]   run
    ${resNameList} =   Create List
    ${laneInfoList}=      Create Dictionary     L0=res1   L1=res2   L2=res3   L3=res4   L4=res5
    ${lane2resNameMappingList}=     Create List
    log to console   LANE ID LIST : ${laneInfoList.keys()}
    :FOR    ${laneID}     IN      @{laneInfoList.keys()}
    \       Append To List  ${resNameList}  ${laneInfoList['${laneID}']}
    \       ${lane2resName}=     Create dictionary   lane=${laneID}   resName=${laneInfoList['${laneID}']}
    \       Append To List  ${lane2resNameMappingList}    ${lane2resName}

    ${resName2resObjMappingList}=      Create Dictionary
    @{resNameList}=   Remove Duplicates  ${resNameList} 
    log to console  res LIST: @{resNameList}
    ${totalres}=  Get length   ${resNameList}
    : FOR    ${index}    IN RANGE    0    ${totalres}
    \       log to console   INDEX:${index} res:${resNameList}[${index}] AFMObj:afm${index}
    \       set to dictionary    ${resName2resObjMappingList}   ${resNameList}[${index}]=afm${index}

    log to console  lane2resNameMappingList: ${lane2resNameMappingList}
    log to console  resName2resObjMappingList: ${resName2resObjMappingList}
    set global variable  ${lane2resNameMappingList}
    set global variable  ${resName2resObjMappingList}

    ${totalObjList}=  create list  ${p1}  ${f1}  ${p2}  ${p3}
    ${totalObjsInTest}=  Get length   ${totalObjList}
    ${totalLanesAvailable}=  Get length   ${lane2resNameMappingList}

    ${totalObjs} =  Set Variable IF  ${totalObjsInTest} > ${totalLanesAvailable}  ${totalLanesAvailable}  ${totalObjsInTest}
    ${object2resMappingList}=      Create Dictionary

    ${resList} =   Create List
    log to console   Attaching res for a total of ${totalObjs} objects based on current availability!
    : FOR    ${index}    IN RANGE    0    ${totalObjs}
    \    log to console   Obj:${totalObjList}[${index}] 
    \    log to console   res: ${lane2resNameMappingList[${index}]['resName']} 
    \    log to console   res Obj:${resName2resObjMappingList['${lane2resNameMappingList[${index}]['resName']}']}
    \    log to console   Lane:${lane2resNameMappingList[${index}]['lane']}
    \    log to console   BW:${lane2resNameMappingList[${index}]['lane']}
    \    ${isKeyPresent}=    Run Keyword And Return Status       Dictionary Should Contain Key       ${object2resMappingList}      ${totalObjList}[${index}]
    \    log to console   KEY:${isKeyPresent}
    \    Run Keyword Unless  ${isKeyPresent}    set to dictionary    ${object2resMappingList}   ${totalObjList}[${index}]=${resList}
    \    log to console  AFTER:object2resMappingList: ${object2resMappingList}
    \    log to console  OBJ:${totalObjList}[${index}] VALUE:${resName2resObjMappingList['${lane2resNameMappingList[${index}]['resName']}']}
    \    log to console   DICT : ${object2resMappingList.keys()}
    \    log to console   DICT : &{object2resMappingList} KEY:${totalObjList}[${index}]
    \    Run Keyword  Append To List  &{object2resMappingList}[${totalObjList}[${index}]]  ${resName2resObjMappingList['${lane2resNameMappingList[${index}]['resName']}']}
    \    ${resList} =   Create List
    log to console  object2resMappingList: ${object2resMappingList}
```

## OUTPUT

DICT-WITH-LISTS                                                       ...LANE   ID LIST : odict_keys(['L0', 'L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4'])
....res LIST: ['res1', 'res2', 'res3', 'res4', 'res5']
DICT-WITH-LISTS                                                         .INDEX:0 res:res1 AFMObj:afm0
INDEX:1 res:res2 AFMObj:afm1
INDEX:2 res:res3 AFMObj:afm2
INDEX:3 res:res4 AFMObj:afm3
INDEX:4 res:res5 AFMObj:afm4
.lane2resNameMappingList: [{'lane': 'L0', 'resName': 'res1'}, {'lane': 'L1', 'resName': 'res2'}, {'lane': 'L2', 'resName': 'res3'}, {'lane': 'L3', 'resName': 'res4'}, {'lane': 'L4', 'resName': 'res5'}]
.resName2resObjMappingList: {'res1': 'afm0', 'res2': 'afm1', 'res3': 'afm2', 'res4': 'afm3', 'res5': 'afm4'}
DICT-WITH-LISTS                                                         ....Attaching res for a total of 4 objects based on current availability!
.Obj:P-1
res: res1
res Obj:afm0
Lane:L0
BW:L0
KEY:False
AFTER:object2resMappingList: {'P-1': []}
OBJ:P-1 VALUE:afm0
DICT : odict_keys(['P-1'])
DICT : {'P-1': []} KEY:P-1
DICT-WITH-LISTS                                                       | FAIL   |
Dictionary '&{object2resMappingList}' has no key '['P-1', 'F-2', 'P-2', 'P-3'][0'.

---

Test                                                                  | FAIL   |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed

Comment: There is this concept of "minimal reproducible example" in SO, it is not a code review system; the next time please limit the code to only the relevant parts of it.

Comment: I wanted to provide insight into how I was using the dictionaries and list. But I will keep in mind to keep the code provided to a minimum. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the way you are referencing the key here, from:

```
Run Keyword  Append To List  &{object2resMappingList}[${totalObjList}[${index}]]  ${resName2resObjMappingList['${lane2resNameMappingList[${index}]['resName']}']}
```

to:

```
Run Keyword  Append To List  ${object2resMappingList['${totalObjList}[${index}]']}  ${resName2resObjMappingList['${lane2resNameMappingList[${index}]['resName']}']}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this worked after removing the addiitonal space between "' $'  But I am not clear on why my usage did'nt work. I was trying to follow the example mentioned in the link https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/2813

Comment: RF has two ways to reference a dictionary's key - either `${a dict['a key']}`, or `${a dict}[a key]`; the second, which you used, is more flaky, esp with variables resolution.

Comment: Thank you. The explanation is very useful. Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: I know of this behavior mainly from experience, and some digging in the variables' resolution code (which is quite complicated, I must say).

Comment: Thank you again for taking the time to respond to my questions so promptly